# Pass Id parameter into ajax function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

AJAX function is not passing Id parameter to GET method in my controller.

I have this table.

```
 @foreach (var user in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@user.LastName</td>
                        <td>@user.Email</td>
                        <td>@string.Join(" , ", user.Roles.ToList())</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="manageRolePopup('@Url.Action("Manage","Role",                                     new {id=user.UserId },Context.Request.Scheme)')">Manage Roles</a>

                            <partial name="_RoleManagePopup.cshtml" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

On click I want to show in popup user first name and last name so I have this in my **Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Manage(string userId)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            ViewBag.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            ViewBag.LastName = user.LastName;

            var model = new ManageRoleViewModel();

            List<string> roleNames = new List<string>();

            foreach(var role in _roleManager.Roles)
            {
                model.RoleId = role.Id;
                roleNames.Add(role.Name);
            }
            model.UserId = user.Id;
            model.RoleNames = roleNames;

            return View(model);
        }
```

**AJAX**

```
manageRolePopup = (url) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
            $("#form-modal .modal-body").html(res);
            $("#form-modal").modal("show");
        }
    })
}
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Role" asp-action="Manage" asp-route-UserId="@Model.UserId">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <h4>@ViewBag.FirstName @ViewBag.LastName</h4>

            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.RoleNames)">
                    <option selected disabled>---Select New Role---</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When im passing Id like below, everything is good. User is not null, Id parameter also.

```
<a asp-controller="Role" asp-action="Manage" asp-route-UserId="user.UserId"></a>
```

Obviously I want to do UPDATE method but for now I just want to have it displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add userId to your ajax url

```
manageRolePopup = (userId) => {

 var url = @Url.Action("Manage","Role");

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url+"?UserId="+userId,
        ....
```

Since you have a list of UserIds you need or add UserId data attribute to you ancore tag, or push it as input parameter

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="manageRolePopup(@user.UserId)>Manage Roles</a>
```

but it is better to use modern javascript syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

 $(document).on("click", ".userBtn", (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    
     var userId= this.id;
    var url = @Url.Action("Manage","Role");

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url+"?UserId="+userId,
        ....
     
    }));

 });
</script>
```

and view

```
<a id="@user.UserId" class="userBtn btn btn-primary"> Manage Roles </a>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Brilliant answer. It solved my problem.  I thought that my onClick method third parameter which is "new [{id=user.UserId}] should be passed to AJAX URL. Could you explain why it does not work?

Comment: @zarpat I updated my answer.

Comment: @zarpat I updated my answer again

Comment: Thank you again Sir. This modern javascript syntax is definitely more clearly.